# How to go to Activity by clicking Table row?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple app. and it is my first app too...

It has an activity with a menu and I made each menu option in a Table Row. Each Table Row contain an Image button and a Text Description. I want to go to another Activity when we click on each Table row. How do I do that??

And is it possible to use a single class file to show multiple layout files (ie. for each menu's content) ?

Or

Is there any other way than tableRow to create a menu like this and use it to go to another Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's see how to go to another activity by clicking on table row.  In table row of your XML file property give this syntax:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Then in your Activity just after on create method put this line

```
public void onClick(View v){

 Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),newActivityname.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent,0);

}
```

By doing this when you click on table row u will be redirected to another activity name `newActivityname`.

Second, yes you can set different layout files for same acitivty just based on some condition.  For example if we want to put layout files as per integer value condition than do like this

```
int flag=0;

if(flag==0){
  setContentView(R.layout.xml1);
}
if(flag==0){
      setContentView(R.layout.xml2);
    }
if(flag==1){
      setContentView(R.layout.xml3);
    }
if(flag==3){
      setContentView(R.layout.xml4);
    }
```

Like this based on some condition you can set your layout.

For your 3rd query please be more specific so that we can answer you.

Comment: Is there anyway to know which Table Row was clicked when we r in next activity?

I want to use the same Java file to show different layout according to the Table Row clicked...

Comment: it's simple as per condition of table row id u can set ur layout programetically

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you can give id to your TableRow and then onClick call the next activity like th below code and in your next activity you can handle the setcontentview() method with simple if-else logic with the values passed from the previous intent(eg  rowId=1 for first row and etc) and set your required layout this may help.

```
TableRow tableRow=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.LayoutFirstRow);
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(presentActivity.this, destinationActivity.class));             
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(this);
tablerow.setId(2000+i); //set id here
tablerow.setOnClickListener(getOnClickTableRow(tablerow));
//your code...

View.OnClickListener getOnClickTableRow(final TableRow tablerow)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //START ACITIVYT HERE
             Intent intent=new Intent(CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this,Activityname.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```